# Eclipse out of sync with file system

Tags: svn, eclipse, subclipse

I am having an eclipse/subclipse problem that occasionally occurs but we cannot reproduce it consistently on my machine or others. When I pull a project, I cannot open the newest changes of some of its files (randomly) in my text editor. Subclipse shows the newest commit just fine. Opening that revision from the svn repository directly (not my package explorer) or even editing the file from terminal shows the correct changes. The only instance this occurs in is when I try to open the new file directly from my package explorer. Updating the file to head fixes this problem, but updating any of the parent folders to head misses the file's updates. Refreshing does not work. I still see the outdated file contents.